# I'm facing problems while achieving the following design in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter, I just got stuck while clipping and trying to get a specific design from a container. I need your help to achieve following UI, actually need to achieve design.

[image]

```
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 120),
    Center(
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: SignInBoxClipper(),
        child: Container(
          width: 280,
          height: 120,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(65, 175, 250, 1),
                  Color.fromRGBO(175, 136, 246, 1),
                ],
                radius: 1.3,
                center: Alignment(-0.9, .5),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload a new image, this is unavailable.